# result set jsp - how to use?

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc

Can someone please tell me why this isn't working? I would like to be able to check if the username/password returned from the DB query is equal to a value.

Session attribute "loginSuccess" always returns false, even if the values should be matching.

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.sql.*" %>
<%
            String driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();

            Connection con = null;
            ResultSet rst = null;
            Statement stmt = null;

            try {
                String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:username/password@url:port:SID";
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
                stmt = con.createStatement();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            if (request.getParameter("action") != null) {
                rst = stmt.executeQuery("select username, password"
                        + " from table");
                }
%>


                <%

                boolean loginCheck = false;
                           int count = 1;
                            while (rst.next()) {

if(request.getParameter("action")!=null){
    if("username1"==rst.getString("username")){
        if("password1"==rst.getString("password")){
            loginCheck = true;
            }
        }
    }

                            count++;
                            }

                           if(loginCheck==true){
                               session.setAttribute("loginSuccess", "true");
                               }else{
                               session.setAttribute("loginSuccess", "false");
                               }

                            rst.close();
                            stmt.close();
                            con.close();
                %>

<jsp:forward page="login.jsp"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using == to compare Strings.   Try equals instead.

I'd recommend not putting scriptlet code in JSPs this way.  You should write JSPs using the JSTL tag library.

I'd also recommend putting that database code in a POJO so that you can you test it off line, separate from your servlet/JSP engine.  Then have a servlet instantiate the POJO, interact with the database, and send the result to the JSP.

It's a bit more work, but the design will extend and scale better in the long run.

Comment: Ha! So simple. I must have been in Javascript mode when I wrote that. Thanks for noticing that!

Comment: Thanks for the additional tips.. still new to this so it is appreciated.

Comment: @etech: I'd also recommend to learn the SQL `WHERE` clause. You're unnecessarily duplicating the entire database table into Java's memory, comparing every row in Java and ignoring the unmatched data. What a waste of resources. Just utilize the SQL powers. Write your SQL query so that it returns exactly the row which matches the username/password. If it returns one row, it's valid. If it returns nothing, it's not valid. Simple as that and more efficient, especially if you've a lot rows in the table ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think that you got a basic grammatical mistake in this line of code.

> "username1"==rst.getString("username")

It should be like this

> rst.getString("username").equalsIgnoreCase("username1");

and the password is similar.
Please check if this can help.

Comment: altho it would be safer to flip the comparison "username1".equalsIgnoreCase(rst.getString("username")) 
as it's possible that there is a null in the database.

Comment: to make sure you can use this "username1".equalsIgnoreCase(rst.getString("username") + ""). If null, null will be cast as String. :))